# Group by nid and Order by date with group ID Drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am using drupal, and I have nodeaccess module. I have many role for a single user. And I have granted many role for a single node.

I need output like the below.

a) Order By Date (first preference)
b) In the date order I need to group by gid

Example

I have wrote a query

```
SELECT n.nid, na.gid, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fav.field_date_posted_value), fav.field_date_posted_value
FROM node as n
JOIN nodeaccess AS na ON na.nid = n.nid 
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_date_posted AS fav ON fav.entity_id = n.nid
ORDER BY fav.field_date_posted_value DESC, n.nid ASC
LIMIT 10
```

I got result as below

```
+-------+-----+-------------------------+
| nid   | gid | field_date_posted_value |
+-------+-----+-------------------------+
| 12501 |   1 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12501 |  10 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12502 |   1 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12502 |   3 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12502 |   8 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12502 |  10 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12502 |  11 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12505 |   1 | 2014-05-05              |
| 12505 |  10 | 2014-05-05              |
| 12575 |   1 | 2014-12-24              |
| 12575 |  10 | 2014-12-24              |
| 12576 |   1 | 2013-05-26              |
| 12576 |  10 | 2013-05-26              |
| 12577 |   1 | 2013-05-14              |
| 12577 |  10 | 2013-05-14              |
+-------+-----+-------------------------+
```

But when I try to group by nid like below

```
SELECT n.nid, na.gid, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fav.field_date_posted_value), fav.field_date_posted_value
FROM node as n
JOIN nodeaccess AS na ON na.nid = n.nid 
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_date_posted AS fav ON fav.entity_id = n.nid
GROUP BY n.nid ORDER BY fav.field_date_posted_value DESC, n.nid ASC
LIMIT 10
```

The result it

```
+-------+-----+-------------------------+
| nid   | gid | field_date_posted_value |
+-------+-----+-------------------------+
| 12501 |  01 | 2014-12-24              |
| 12502 |  11 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12505 |  01 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12575 |  01 | 2014-05-26              |
| 12576 |  01 | 2013-05-14              |
| 12577 |  01 | 2013-05-05              |
+-------+-----+-------------------------+
```

But my expected result is

```
+-------+-----+-------------------------+
| nid   | gid | field_date_posted_value |
+-------+-----+-------------------------+
| 12501 |  10 | 2014-12-24              |
| 12502 |  11 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12505 |  10 | 2014-12-07              |
| 12575 |  10 | 2014-05-26              |
| 12576 |  10 | 2013-05-14              |
| 12577 |  10 | 2013-05-05              |
+-------+-----+-------------------------+
```

Is there any way to do this?

I want to reorder my result as **group by nid** and **ordered by date(DESC)** and **order by gid (DESC)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using aggregate functions on the `gid` and `field_date_posted_value` columns, which is what you should be doing anyway in a proper `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT n.nid,
       MAX(na.gid),
       MAX(fav.field_date_posted_value)
FROM node AS n
JOIN nodeaccess AS na
    ON na.nid = n.nid 
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_date_posted AS fav
    ON fav.entity_id = n.nid
GROUP BY n.nid
ORDER BY fav.field_date_posted_value DESC,
         n.nid ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Actually, since the `nid` column seems to perfectly correlate with the `field_date_posted_value` column, you might be able to group on both of these columns, i.e. use this:

```
SELECT n.nid, MAX(na.gid), fav.field_date_posted_value
FROM ...
...
GROUP BY n.nid, fav.field_date_posted_value
```